# Is it okay to store dynamic data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose with nodejs.
For example I have a schema like that.

```
new Schema({
  x: Number,
  y: Number
});
```

My application needs difference of this props in a multiple places. It will be better if I will get this value from db rather than calculating it each time. So I need something like

```
new Schema({
  x: Number,
  y: Number,
  diff: this.x - this.y
})
```

Is it okay to do so? If yes, how I can do that?

Comment: `diff` can also be a Number and when you are adding a document to the collection you can just calculate and store the difference.

Comment: @Ramesh yes, I know that, but I'd prefer database do that for me (due to structure of an app). Something like procedures in SQL.

Comment: You can either write a function in node.js and hit the mongoose model to write to DB or else you can write & execute a Js func in mongoose schema - here in second approach you would just pass in inputs to schema (x & y), Anyhow at the end, both of these have common thing called a Js func needs to be there to get this done on inserts but on updates you can get it offloaded to DB as long as your DB version is > `4.2`!! If wanted to go in the route of writing Js func in mongoose schema I can provide you info..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store derived data in the database. Especially if calculations are expensive there are many cases where this makes a lot of sense.

> If yes, how I can do that?

Most frequently the derived data is calculated in the application.

MongoDB also provides [views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/).